# Rich content field not displaying in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, richtextarea

I am trying to display the content of a rich text field in a LWC.  Nothing is displaying.  Below is my code:

```
public with sharing class ProjectController {
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static Project2__c[] getAllProjects() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Project_Title__c, Category_text__c, Project_URL__c, Project_Organizations__c, test__c
        FROM Project2__c WHERE Category_text__c='Awarded' ORDER BY Project_Title__c];
}

@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static Project2__c[] searchProjects(String searchTerm) {
    // Return all projects when no search term
    searchTerm = searchTerm.trim();
    if (searchTerm == '') {
        return getAllProjects();
    }
    // Prepare query paramters
    searchTerm = '%'+ searchTerm +'%';
    // Execute search query
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Project_Title__c, Project_Type__c, Project_URL__c, Project_Organizations__c, test__c
        FROM Project2__c WHERE (Category_text__c='Awarded') AND ((Name LIKE :searchTerm) OR (Project_Type__c LIKE :searchTerm) OR 
        (Project_Title__c LIKE :searchTerm) OR (Project_Organizations__c LIKE :searchTerm)) ORDER BY Name LIMIT 50];
}
```

}

```
<template>

    <div >
        <!-- Start project list -->
        <template if:true={projects.data}>
                <lightning-input type="search"
                onchange={handleSearchTermChange}
                variant="label-hidden"
                class="slds-m-bottom_small partial-width"
                label="Search"
                placeholder="Search for projects"
                value={searchTerm}>
            </lightning-input>
            <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true"  >
                <template for:each={projects.data} for:item="project">
                    <lightning-layout-item key={project.Id} size="3" class="NIIMBL-project-list">
                        <!-- Start project tile -->
                        <div class="Project-Title">
                        <a href={project.Project_URL__c}>{project.Project_Title__c}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Project-Participants-Label">
                            Participants
                        </div>
                        <div class="Project-Orgs">
                            <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={test__c}>
                            </lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End project tile -->
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
            <!-- No projects found -->
```

No projects meeting the search criteria were found.
        
    
            
            
            
            
                
                    An error occurred while loading the project list

Comment: Where is the component javascript that sets `test__c`?

Comment: Yeah, where is getAllProjects wired into? likely a collection, right? and is the rich text to display for every item in a for loop? Please, provide better context of the code you are using.

Comment: I updated my entry to show the full HTML and Controller files

Comment: You still didn't post the Javascript Controller but I'm going to guess that you should be using {project.test__c} instead (you are missing the reference to the record from where the field is being pulled from)

Comment: Glen - that was it.  Thank you.  I think I need to go to bed.  I can't believe I was missing that.  I had it on my other fields.